# Abort() has been called when trying to run ImPlot::BeginPlot in windows 10 visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, imgui, implot

Project settings have been made to run imgui and it runs successfully
Implot related files are also compiled and the program is executed.
When the ImPlot::BeginPlot function is added, the program displays the Abort window immediately after execution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSugz.png)

please guide me to run implot